# Am I testing correctly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a `Camel` app that is integrated with `spring` and i would like to write tests for it. Here's my app:

camel-config.xml

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="converter" />
</camelContext>

<bean id="converter" class="Converter"/>
```

class to be tested:

```
@Component
public class Converter extends SpringRouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    final XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    xmlJsonFormat.setTypeHints(String.valueOf("YES"));

    from("ftp://Mike@localhost?" +
            "noop=true&binary=true&consumer.delay=5s&include=.*xml")
            .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"), FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(new File("data", "repo.dat")))
            .marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file://data").process(
            new Processor() {
                //System.out.println();
            }
        });
   }
}
```

And here's my testing class:

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Override
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = super.createCamelContext();       
    context.addComponent("ftp", context.getComponent("seda"));
    return context;
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {                
            from("ftp://Mike@localhost").to("mock:quote");
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testSameMessageArrived() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint quote = getMockEndpoint("mock:quote");
    FileReader fl = new FileReader("D:\\test\\asdasd.txt");
    quote.expectedBodiesReceived(fl);
    template.sendBody("ftp://Mike@localhost", fl);
    quote.assertIsSatisfied();
}
}
```

This test passes, but I'm not sure that it's the right way to test this particular program.
Could you please tell me if I'm doing it right, or I should test it other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to not rewrite the route. Use your actual route instead.

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new Converter();
}
```

And then use [camel-mock](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html), this let you intercept existing endpoint like this:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // mock all endpoints
        mockEndpoints();
    }
});

getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:start").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");
```

Or with patterns:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // mock only log endpoints
        mockEndpoints("log*");
    }
});

// now we can refer to log:foo as a mock and set our expectations
getMockEndpoint("mock:log:foo").expectedBodiesReceived("Bye World");
```

If you want more info on testing with Camel, I seriously advice you to read the "Camel in Action" book.

**EDIT:** here is a response of Claus Ibsen to a similar question ([stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553254/1292605)).

You can do integration testing with a dedicated or embedded FTP server or you can use mocks for unit testing, depending on what you want to test. You could also do both.

Comment: I'm reading this book, but haven't found similar example.
I also added `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. Now i can see test coverage of my class.
One more thing:
I'm not supposed to have physical connection to my ftp server am I? And it doesn't matter what i put into `expectedBodiesReceived` my tests always pass. It's not supposed to be so, right?